# php make nested array from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I want to make a nicely structured category with parent tree, but i can't seem to find the right way to get do this properly.
This is the premis:
1 product has many categories.
1 category may have a parent.

this is the array I currently have (the values in these arrays are just an example)

```
array:4[
  1=> array:2 [
    2 =>2 
    4 => 4
  ]
  2=> array:1[
    3=>3
  ]
  3=> array:1[
    5=>5
  ]
  9=> array:1[
    6=>6
  ]
]
```

now i want this

```
array:4[
  1=> array:2 [
    2 => array:1 [
      3=> array:1 [
        5=>5
      ]
    ] 
    4 => 4
  ]
  9=> array:1[
    6=>6
  ]
]
```

how do I convert the first to the second while keeping the array keys, I want to use the keys to call upon an another array with all the relevant objects and data
so i can get this as a result:
http://www.bootply.com/dFeKoQmgb2

Comment: If the first array would contain a key '5', the output array should been one level deeper, am I correct? If that is the case, you'll need to search on recursion. :-)

Comment: well not exactly, the numbers are just relevant for the structure, these numbers will never be the same. the array key is the parent_id and the value is a list of children, I want to combine all the parents and the children with the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now I fixed it using this function, I'm sure there is a more elegant way, since it only works when the parent is also in the array, for this but it works

```
    array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'parent' => int 1
      'name' => string 'voluptatem' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 3
      'parent' => int 2
      'name' => string 'qui' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 4
      'parent' => int 1
      'name' => string 'qui' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 5
      'parent' => int 3
      'name' => string 'voluptate' (length=9)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 6
      'parent' => int 9
      'name' => string 'optio' (length=5)


private function generatePageTree($datas, $parent=0, $limit=0)
    {
        if ($limit > 100) return '';
        $tree='<ul class="list-group">';
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
            if ($data['parent'] == $parent) {
                $tree.='<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading' . $data['id'] . '">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title" style="height:50px;">
                                        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion" href="#collapse' . $data['id'] . '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse' . $data['id'] . '">
                                            ' . $data['name'] . '
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="' . action('CategoryController@show', $data['id']) . '" class="btn btn-default navbar-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Toon</a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapse' . $data['id'] . '" class="panel-collapse collapse out" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading' . $data['id'] . '">
                                    <div class="panel-body">';
                $tree.=$this->generatePageTree($datas, $data['id'], $limit ++);
                $tree.='</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        ';
            }
        }
        $tree.='</ul>';

        return $tree;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try the following code. Note that there must be a better approach without changing the source array inside recursion.

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(
        2 => 2,
        4 => 4
    ),
    2 => array(
        3 => 3
    ),
    3 => array(
        5 => 5
    ),
    9 => array(
        6 => 6
    )
);

//we need the copy to delete there nodes that have been re-atached. Otherwise, we end up changing the array itself within recursion, which is not good
$arrayCopy = $array;

function recursive(&$array, &$arrayCopy) {
    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
        //if we found the leaf node
        if(!is_array($value)) {
            // and there is something in the array copy with this index
            if(array_key_exists($key, $arrayCopy)) {
                // re-attach it to the initial array. $value is passed by reference. BTW, not a good approach as I stated above, but it works on the sample data
                $value = $arrayCopy[$key];
                // remove that node from array copy in order to not double process it.
                unset($arrayCopy[$key]);
                // call it again for the leaf-node value
                recursive($value, $arrayCopy);
            }
            // here is recursion exit, if we don't find anything in the arracy copy for the fiven leaf node
        } else {
            //recursive call it for the node
            recursive($value, $arrayCopy);
        }
    }
}
// launch the recursion
recursive($array, $arrayCopy);

// now we need to remove the nodes that have been removed from the array copy, i.e. the ones being re-attached. We could not do this in the recursion
$result = array();
foreach(array_keys($arrayCopy) as $initial_key) {
    $result[$initial_key] = $array[$initial_key];
}

var_dump($result);
```